# Поиск ID выбранных элементов

Tags: c#, база-данных, winforms, list, поиск

Есть combobox с мультивыбором ([источник](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31105/A-ComboBox-with-a-CheckedListBox-as-a-Dropdown)). В него из БД приходят items. Пользователь что-то выбирает. Нужно этот набор вернуть в базу (точнее в связную таблицу добавить ID выбранных элементов).

1. Можно для каждого элемента делать запрос в БД, чтобы узнавать ID.
2. Можно изначально (когда идет наполнение) брать из БД еще и ID.

Во втором случае вижу такое решение. Полученный набор "ID - Значение" добавлять в List с типом кастом класса (с двумя полями). Когда получены "значения" от пользователя - запустить цикл с одним условием на поиск совпадения. Откуда и можно получить набор ID для всех выбранных элементов.

Можно ли во втором случае без перебора в цикле получить ID зная значение?

Comment: `Windows Forms` или `WPF` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно я неправильно понял вопрос, но `CheckedComboBox.CheckedItems` вернет список значений Вашего класса. Соответственно, и ID и наименование («значение») будут доступны.

Например, у Вас есть класс:

```
class CCBoxItem
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name{get;set;}

    public CCBoxItem(int id, string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        ID = id;
    }
}
```

Вы загружаете список ID-Name из БД, затем добавляете их в `CheckedComboBox`:

```
List<CCBoxItem> items = //загрузка из БД
ccb.Items.AddRange(items.ToArray());
ccb.DisplayMember = "Name";
ccb.ValueSeparator = ", ";
```

После того как пользователь что-нибудь выбрал, обращаетесь к `CheckedItems` и получаете то, что Вам нужно:

```
foreach (CCBoxItem item in ccb.CheckedItems)
{
    //хотите ID
    Console.WriteLine(item.ID);
    //хотите Name
    Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
}
```

Comment: Скрее всего придется делать вот так `foreach (CCBoxItem item in ccb.CheckedItems.OfType<CCBoxItem>()){...}`

Comment: @tym32167 Не совсем понял зачем. Там ведь и так неявный `Cast`, если тип не сойдется то будет выброшено исключение.

Comment: Я могу ошибаться, но помню случаи, когда для каких то child коллекций это не работало, откзывалось кастить и падала ошибка компилятора. Но сейчас не могу воспроизвести.